# Laravel Spatie Query Builder: right way to consume API with Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, query-string, laravel-query-builder

On Laravel backend i have `customers.index` controller method :

```
$result = $department->Customers()->getQuery();

        $result = QueryBuilder::for($result)
            ->allowedFilters([
                'title',
                'description',
                'email',
                'phone'
            ])
            ->defaultSort('title')
            ->allowedSorts([
                'title',
                'email'
            ]);    

        $result = $result->paginate($request->per_page ?: 10)->appends(request()->query());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => '',
            'data' => $result
        ]);
```

now in Vuejs frontend i want querystring to be like

```
 host/api/customer?page=2&per_page=15&filter[title]=foo
```

i tried this approach :

```
const params = {
        page: this.page,
        per_page: 15,
        filter: {
          search: this.query
        }
      };    

      console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
      this.$axios
        .get(`/api/customer`, {
          params
        });
```

but the querystring became:

```
customer?0=%7B%22page%22:1,%22per_page%22:15,%22filter%22:%7B%22search%22:%221231%22%7D%7D
```

i have other option: use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like :

```
api/customer?filter[search]=${this.query}&page=${this.page}&per_page=${this.per_page}
```

- Question 1:

  how to get right querystring from params object
- Question 2:

  is there any documentation on this `filter[title]=...` querystring way ? how can i use them in AND , Or cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are setting your query strings as the options.

```
this.$axios
    .get(`/api/customer`, {
        params
    });
```

Should be.

```
this.$axios
    .get(`/api/customer`, {
        params: params
});
```

They have a [Documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering). If you want to do complex logic, i would probably look in to how it handles [scopes](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering#scope-filters). Then do you logic in a `Laravel` scope and let the builder handle them.